# Some doubts related to the clear property on the footer in a tabless layout

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I  have implement the following fixed tabless layout using HTML+CSS: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

(I have to finalize some settings)

This layout have two floatted columns **#content** and **#sidebar** and under these columns there is placed the footer div **#footcontainer**

Ok, so I have to clear the elements that I would to place under the tow columns (bring back the elements in the normal flow of the document), to do this I use the **clear** CSS property.

I have read that I could do that in some differents way.

In my example I have created an empty div having id **clearer2** that have the following CSS settings:

```
#clearer2{
    clear: both;
}
```

This work well, but I know that I could also clear directly the footercontainer, in this way:

```
#footcontainer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 200px;
    background: #4f4f4f url(../images/bgfooter.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -13px 25px 5px #b2b2b2;
}
```

At logic level should be the same thing because I set the **clear: both;** property on an item and then this property is valid for all the successive items. But reading online it seems to me that the first solution is better then the second one. Why is better to creat a new item (as an empty div) that clear then do it directly on the appropriate element (in the example the div **#footercontainer**)

The solution that I have use is a valid solution?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs with `clear: both` property make their parent divs expand their height as one could expect when they have only floated divs inside, as explained in http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html (labeled "The old solution").

So in your example, this is what `clear: both` is achieving. You don't need to reset the normal flow, because your main divs (`#container` and `#footcontainer`) are on the same div hierarchy level, and not floated.

You may want to add these properties to `#container` to make it expand correctly:

```
#container {
    ...
    overflow: auto;
    width: 770px; /* Needed for some older browsers */
}
```